# Указ путя к файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, аудио, path

Есть код, по нажатию клавиши `Play` `sound` должен производиться звук. Путь вроде указал верно, но звук не издаётся.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.sound = QSound('D:\Downloads\1605369153_Clap 14.wav', self)              # 1

        self.play_btn = QPushButton('Play Sound', self)
        self.play_btn.clicked.connect(self.sound.play)       # 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените:

```
QSound('D:\Downloads\1605369153_Clap 14.wav', self)
```

на

```
QSound('D:\\Downloads\\1605369153_Clap 14.wav', self)
```

или

```
QSound('D:/Downloads/1605369153_Clap 14.wav', self)
```